# how to add raft instead of kafka in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

How to add **raft** instead of kafka in hyperledger fabric altoros fabric-supply-chain project ? 
    **here's my configtxtemplate-OneOrg-orderer.yaml file**

```
---
################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    OrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *ORG1
    common:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *ORG1

    CHANNEL_NAME:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            Organizations:
                - *ORG1

################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/DOMAIN/msp

    - &ORG1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: ORG1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: ORG1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/ORG1.DOMAIN/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.ORG1.DOMAIN
              Port: 7051


################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.DOMAIN:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:
```

Can you please check where I'm going wrong and in which files i have to make changes.
I went through the docs of raft but i couldn't understand it well and there is no good source or tutorial that i could go through. If you know any good source or example then please help. 
I see the hyperledger fabric community is not as strong as bitcoin or ethereum like blockchains. I am facing lot of trouble to build an application on it. I would request you to help me from where i can learn the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/raft_configuration.html) for more details and explanations, while key concepts are:

1. In order to work with Raft you need to configure your ordering service to work with TLS.
2. Change orderer type to be

   ```
   OrdererType: etcdraft
   ```
3. You need to setup your concenters set (Raft replicas) by adding into configuration following section:

   ```
   Consenters:

       - Host: raft0.example.com
         Port: 7050
         ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert0
         ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert0
       - Host: raft1.example.com
         Port: 7050
         ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert1
         ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert1
       - Host: raft2.example.com
         Port: 7050
         ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert2
         ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert2
   ```

where you provide configuration to setup your cluster including TLS certificates for your concenters.

For example profile for Raft might look as following, `SampleDevModeEtcdRaft` profile:

```
SampleDevModeEtcdRaft:
  <<: *ChannelDefaults
Capabilities:
  <<: *ChannelCapabilities
  Orderer:
    <<: *OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    EtcdRaft:
    Consenters:
        - Host: raft0.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert0
          ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert0
        - Host: raft1.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert1
          ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert1
        - Host: raft2.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: path/to/ClientTLSCert2
          ServerTLSCert: path/to/ServerTLSCert2        
  Organizations:
      - *OrdererOrg
    Capabilities:
      <<: *OrdererCapabilities
  Application:
    <<: *ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    - <<: *OrdererOrg
  Consortiums:
    SampleConsortium:
      Organizations:
      - *Org1
      - *Org2
```

Comment: thanks , i was also able to up my docker network buy first killing all docker containers and then generating the artifacts using ./network.sh -m generate -o etcdraft 
and then using ./network.sh -m up

Comment: yes, forgot to mention you have an example in fabric-samples.

Comment: I am going through the docs and i found this.
Note: an orderer will be listed as a consenter in the system channel as well as any application channels they’re joined to.
Can you please explain why and how to add in application channel as right now the etcdraft is used as ordering service in system channel only.

Comment: Where did you guys get ClientTLSCert / ServerTLSCert from can the fabric-ca-server generate them ? If so how ?

Or can you use any cert / key from openssl

Comment: @RVandersteen, the cryptogen tool generates all cryptographic elements includeing the above.